# SHFB presentation style 2022, Toc not visible

Tags: tableofcontents, sandcastle, shfb

I use Sandcastle (SHFB) in this configuration

1. Plug-ins : content only
2. Build > Presentation : Default 2022
3. Help file format : Website

When I look at the after build rendering, the table of contents (Toc) does not appear in the website.
If I change 'Default 2022' to 'VS2013' it's OK (the TOC appears on the left).
I can't find any settings to change. Is there a way to show the TOC for the 'Default 2022' style
?
thks